# Subtotal less coupons/discounts on order confirmation page of Magento

Tags: magento

On the Order Confirmation page of Magento 1.5 (using the template , I have the a number of analytics conversion code scripts (like Google AdWords Conversion tracking).

The code that is currently used to get the subtotal is

```
<?php $order_id = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getLastRealOrderId(); ?>
<?php $order_details = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($order_id); ?>
<?php $subtotal = $order_details->subtotal; ?>
```

And then the $subtotal variable is used throughout. The problem is that this is the subtotal BEFORE any coupons or discounts are applied. I need it to be the total AFTER coupons or discounts.

Can anyone help me with the code to get at that value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call `var_dump($order_details->debug())` to see all the data fields of the order object. I don't see anything that matches the subtotal with discount, but I do see a `discount_amount` field, which has the total discount amount (as a negative number); add this to your subtotal.

If you want the grand total, with discounts and shipping included, use the `grand_total` field.

Comment: Looks like it works just fine adding the discount_amount to the subtotal. Thank you!